# Associate an Activity with an item in XML ListViews in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-widget, listviewitem

I have a ListView that is populated using an XML file.  However, I want each item, when clicked, to start a new Activity related to that item.

I understand how to use OnItemClick to start a Toast that shows the selected item's text.  However, since the ListView is populated from an XML there is not a specific Id for each item in the list.

So, how would I associate an Activity with each item in the ListView when the items do not have Ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain in your XML file a node for the Activity that has to be called, in a numeric or string format. Then have a list of activities in a collection, that are implementing a certain interface/abstract class, so that you can loop on it. Also activities have a static field/method that return their reference number or string so you can compare too.

Some sketch:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <category
        name="Item One"
        id="grp1" />
    <category
        name="Item Two"
        id="grp2" />
</resources>
```

In Java:

```
    List<AbstractTable> col = new ArrayList<AbstractTable>();
    col.add(new clsGroup1(this.ctx));
    col.add(new clsGroup2(this.ctx));

    for (AbstractTablecls : col) {
                if (cls.getTag().equals(varFromListSelection)) {
                         //launch intent of this class
                }
            }
```

where `getTag()` returns the identifier for the class eg: `grp1` or `grp2`